# glTexImage2D - uploading a new image for the same texture id

Tags: opengl

Here is an example code:

```
//img1 2048x2048
//img2 1024x1024

glGenTextures(1, &texId);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, img1.getWidth(), img1.getHeight(), 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img1.accessPixels());
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

//in  other function
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, img2.getWidth(), img2.getHeight(), 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img2.accessPixels());
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

As you can see I use the same texture id for uploading two different images. I use nvidia-smi for monitoring gpu memory usage. A memory used by the texture equals 20 MiB. It doesn't matter which image is uploaded first. If I call a second glTexImage2D just after the first one without rebinding a texture then memory usage equals 4 MiB:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, img1.getWidth(), img1.getHeight(), 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img1.accessPixels());
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, img2.getWidth(), img2.getHeight(), 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img2.accessPixels());
```

Does it mean that opengl doesn't free a memory when other image is uploaded with the same texture id after rebinding a texture ?

Comment: Reusing a texture has sense when parameters and sizes are all the same. When only a part of the texture is re-filled, then there's `glTexSubImage_D` to do that job. There's no advantage against delete and create a new texture in other case.

Comment: I know but want to create a wrapper which monitors a texture memory usage and above scenarios are theoretically possible.

Comment: The OpenGL specification doesn't allow GPU memory handling, as you would do with C++. It's the driver who decides when to delete GPU memory, even if you issued a `glDelete___XX` command,

Comment: In theory yes, but in practice after glDelete a texture memory is freed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Texture names (= IDs) are just abstract handles. And between [synchronization points](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Synchronization) a single texture name may in fact refer to an arbitrary number of images.

Consider this order of operations:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, the_texture);

glTexImage2D(…);
glDraw…();

glTexImage2D(…);
glDraw…();

glTexImage2D(…);
glDraw…();
```

Due to the *as-if* rule, each `glDraw…` operation must draw with the texture data that has been uploaded most recently. However due to the aynchronous nature of OpenGL, the actual drawing operations may be delayed until (much) later. Hence in the meantime the OpenGL implementation must hold on to the various texture images until the drawing is complete.

Comment: Even if I call a second glTexImage2D just after the first one but with rebinding a texture the effect is the same - a texture memory usage equals 20 MiB. Does it mean that rebinding a texture acts as a synchronization point (glDraw in your example) ?

Comment: @Irbis: Technically texture binds are not synchronization points. However the internals of OpenGL implementations are, by definition, opaque, so *any* behavior with respect to memory consumption is perfectly permissable.

Comment: Just from curiosity - Could you please check a scenario described above in your environment and post results  ? I use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Nvidia Driver 440.82